# what is the javascript equivalent of the audio element

Tags: javascript, audio

Assume the following audio element

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Now I would like to do the same with javascript

```
var audio new Audio( 'horse.mp3' ) ;
```

So the question is how I could also provide the 'ogg' so the 'audio' object can determine which it can play ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Javascript class doesn't support fallbacks, so you have two options:

1. Check to see if the client can play a type of codec and create the
   `Audio` depending on support.
2. Create DOM elements and inject them to the page.

To check to see if there's support for an encoding;

```
var audio = new Audio();
if (audio.canPlayType("audio/ogg; codecs=vorbis")) {
    audio = new Audio("file.ogg");
} else ...
```

DOM injection;

```
var el = document.createElement('audio');
el.innerHTML = '<source src="file.ogg" type="audio/ogg" /><source src="file.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />';
document.body.appendChild(el);
```

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of any tag in JS in `createElement` and `setAttribute`.

```
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
audio.setAttribute('controls', 'controls');

var ogg = document.createElement('source');
ogg.setAttribute('src', 'horse.ogg');
ogg.setAttribute('type', 'audio/ogg');

var mp3 = document.createElement('source');
mp3.setAttribute('src', 'horse.mp3');
mp3.setAttribute('type', 'audio/mp3');

audio.appendChild(ogg);
audio.appendChild(mp3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use audio|video.canPlayType(type)

Example :

```
var canPlayMpeg = audio.canPlayType("audio/mpeg");
```

You can also use a lib like buzz.js http://buzz.jaysalvat.com